# Sharing a common value in all enum values

Tags: enums, rust

I have the following code where every variant of the enum `Message` has a `Term` value associated with it:

```
type Term = usize;
pub enum Message {
    AppendRequest(Term),
    AppendResponse(Term),
    VoteRequest(Term),
    VoteResponse(Term),
}

impl Message {
    pub fn term(&self) -> Term {
        match *self {
            Message::AppendRequest(term)  => term,
            Message::AppendResponse(term) => term,
            Message::VoteRequest(term) => term,
            Message::VoteResponse(term) =>term,
        }
    }
}
```

I want to, given a `Message` be able to get its term without having to deconstruct the actual `Message` value I have. The best I could come up with was creating a public function that unpacked the value for me, but this feels clunky. If I ever add a new enum value, I'm going to have to remember to update match statement in the `term` function.

Is there a more succinct/ergonomic way to express the code above? Is there some way to say "hey, every value for this enum will have also have a `Term` value associated with it.

Comment: *I'm going to have to remember to update match statement in the term function* — the compiler will remind you of that.

Comment: @Shepmaster sure. The complier will catch that. Perhaps what I should've said was "now I have to update code in two places everytime there's a change and the feels like I'm doing something wrong".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Is there some way to say "hey, every value for this enum will have also have a `Term` value associated with it.

No.  This is usually handled by splitting the `enum` into two parts, with a `struct` containing all the common parts:

```
pub struct Message {
    term: Term,
    kind: MessageKind,
}

pub enum MessageKind {
    AppendRequest,
    AppendResponse,
    VoteRequest,
    VoteResponse,
}
```

Answer (score 16):

One option is to implement the `Deref` (and/or `DerefMut`) trait to convert to the common part.

You still have to update that implementation each time you add to the Enum, but there is less boilerplate at the point of use.

E.g., an example below, note that `main` accesses the field `number` on the Enum.

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::string::String;

enum JudgedNumber {
    GoodNumber(Number),
    BadNumber(Number, String),
}

struct Number { number: i32 }

fn main() {
    let nice = JudgedNumber::GoodNumber(Number{number: 42});
    let naughty = JudgedNumber::BadNumber(
        Number{number: 666}, "Damn you to hell".to_string());
    println!("j1 = {}", j1.number);
    println!("j2 = {}", j2.number);
}

impl Deref for JudgedNumber {
    type Target = Number;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Number {
        match self {
            JudgedNumber::GoodNumber(n) => n,
            JudgedNumber::BadNumber(n, _) => n,
        }
    }
}
```

I learnt this from https://github.com/rust-embedded/svd/blob/master/src/svd/cluster.rs

Comment: Cool! Really like this one! But if the common field has a type that is common (e.g. a string) and you don't feel like having a struct with a single string, I suppose other solutions might be preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

DK's response is very good for a case when you don't have any significant non-common data in enum variants. When you have methods to handle structs inside specific variants passing common field around get pretty tedious:

```rust
type Term = usize;

struct AppendRequest {
    // Some fields
}

struct AppendResponse {
    // Some fields
}

// other structs

enum MessageKind {
    AppendRequest(AppendRequest),
    AppendResponse(AppendResponse),
    VoteRequest(VoteRequest),
    VoteResponse(VoteResponse),
}

struct Message {
    term: Term,
    kind: MessageKind,
}

fn append(term:Term, request: &AppendRequest) -> (Term, AppendResponse) {
    println!("The term: {}", term);
    todo!()
}
```

So after I landed on this page for, like, 10-th time I wrote a [macro lib](https://crates.io/crates/enum_common_fields) to generate getters like the one in the question. Now the code in question whould look like this:

```rust
use enum_common_fields::EnumCommonFields;

type Term = usize;

struct AppendRequest {
    term: Term,
    // Some fields
}

struct AppendResponse {
    term: Term,
    // Some fields
}

// other structs


#[derive(EnumCommonFields)]
#[common_field(term: String)]
enum Message {
    AppendRequest(AppendRequest),
    AppendResponse(AppendResponse),
    VoteRequest(VoteRequest),
    VoteResponse(VoteResponse),
}

fn append(request: &AppendRequest) -> AppendResponse {
    println!("The term: {}", request.term());
    todo!()
}
```