# How do I filter a vector of an enum of different structs using a common field?

Tags: filter, rust, enums, iterator

I found you can create a vector of different types of structs using an enum. When filtering the vector on a common field, such as `id`, the compiler doesn't know the type while iterating:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc}; // 0.4.19
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}; // 1.0.126

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize, Clone)]
pub enum TransactionsEnum {
    TransactionOrderA(TransactionOrderA),
    TransactionOrderB(TransactionOrderB),
}
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct TransactionOrderA {
    pub id: i64,
    pub accountID: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct TransactionOrderB {
    pub id: i64,
    pub time: DateTime<Utc>,
}

fn transactions_filter(
    transactions_vector: Vec<TransactionsEnum>,
    x: i64,
) -> Vec<TransactionsEnum> {
    transactions_vector
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|e| e.id >= x)
        .collect()
}
```

```
error[E0609]: no field `id` on type `&TransactionsEnum`
  --> src/lib.rs:27:23
   |
27 |         .filter(|e| e.id >= x)
   |                       ^^
```

[Sharing a common value in all enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49186751/155423) and [Is there a way to directly access a field value in an enum struct without pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54061281/155423) indirectly answer my question, but the answer provided here helped me understand why a `match` statement is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not a common field, they are completely unrelated fields. The fact that they share a name is, as far as the Rust compiler is concerned, an insignificant coincidence. You need to use pattern matching to get the field from either case

```rust
impl TransactionsEnum {
    pub fn id(&self) -> i64 {
        match self {
            TransactionsEnum::TransactionOrderA(value) => value.id,
            TransactionsEnum::TransactionOrderB(value) => value.id,
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
transactions_vector
    .into_iter()
    .filter(|e| e.id() >= x) // Note the parentheses since we're calling a function now
    .collect()
```